# Django heroku application wont run

Tags: python, django, heroku

i was deploying a django project this is my prjoect github https://github.com/EpicGL/CM1

im getting this[

```
2022-03-25T19:04:21.335972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-cm1.herokuapp.com request_id=8c9ac21d-96a7-4563-80df-8e2c60bd98ea fwd="202.134.14.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https.
2022-03-25T19:04:22.514399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-cm1.herokuapp.com request_id=bcd22f6d-8ddb-43b0-8a66-5e5c79f0d2d7 fwd="202.134.14.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

error can anyone please help

hi there,
i was deploying a django project this is my prjoect github https://github.com/EpicGL/CM1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Procfile` was misconfigured.

```
web: gunicorn fullsite.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python fullsit/settings.py
```

Comment: Still getting the same error